# Deus Ex: Human Revolution Director's Cut - Micro Stuttering

Tags: pc, deus-ex-human-revolution

The game has a lot of micro-stutters throughout gameplay, most notably when entering new areas or loading in from the menus. I have tried some registry tweaks as dictated on the Steam support forums, but I cannot see much of a difference. It's not like it breaks the game, but it can be pretty annoying.

One thing to note: I have a dual monitor setup. Whereas most games will launch on the main monitor, with the desktop background still displaying on the secondary, this game does not do so. The secondary screen stays blank. I don't know if this has anything to do with it or not but I'm not sure what it means.

My computer is no slouch either, here are the specs:

Intel Quad Core @ 2.33 GHZ

NVIDIA GeForce 560 running 350.12

8 GB DDR3 ram

Has anyone else experienced this issue, and has had the registry fixes not work? Are there any solutions?

Comment: Micro-stuttering is symptom of SLI/Crossfire configurations (two or more graphics cards), you're probably just seeing stuttering. Also your specs are a bit on the low side barely meeting the recommended requirements.

Comment: Barely?


Processor: 2 GHz dual core
 
Memory: 2 GB RAM 

Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 8000 series or ATI Radeon HD 2000 series or better 

DirectX: Version 9.0c 

Hard Drive: 17 GB available space 

Sound Card: 100% DirectX 9.0c compatible sound device

Comment: @RossRidge I'm very above the minimum.

Comment: Those are the minimum requirements. The **recommended** requirements are a Core 2 quad-core and AMD Radeon HD 5850. Your CPU is not much faster than the slowest Core 2 Quad and the HD 5850 is the equivalent to a GeForce 560 GTX. And sorry, you're also not "very above" the minimum either. Your CPU was on the low-end even back when Deus Ex: Human Revolution came out.

Comment: @RossRidge This wouldn't explain why it only stutters on loading in. I have no troubles in between, performance is fine otherwise.

Comment: It has to be noted that Director's Cut edition was based on older, *buggier* build of Deus Ex:HR, which excludes all the patches and fixes made to the game after about half of its lifetime, I've heard reports of bugs that were fixed in the regular edition but came back in DC and was never fixed. It's most likely that your problem is one such bug. For reference, I used to run the regular version on Intel E4600 @2.5Ghz, 2GB RAM and NVIDIA 9800GT, never had any stuttering.